# PL/SQL Food Industry "Julian" Date Conversion

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some 5 digits dates in a format that the food industry generally calls "Julian" dates (Warning: these are not the "Julian" dates you are familiar with. It's misused terminology that "stuck" and became the standard in the industry. Don't comment on that, it's just how it is.)

The first 3 digits of these "Julian" dates are a number representing the day of a year.

```
Example: 
    January 1 = 001
    January 2 = 002
    December 31 = 365 or 366
```

The next two digits are the last two digits of the year. 2015 = 15.

For example 22215 = August 10, 2015 (I believe).

I need an Oracle SQL statement that convers these "dates" into standard dates to join to other date data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A co-worker found the answer.  The "DDD" format:

```
SELECT to_date('36515', 'DDDYY') FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Make sure you test with leap year dates and that dates returned are as expected and match correctly with your data.

Comment: What's about the "Year 2000 Problem"? Maybe better use `to_date('36515', 'DDDRR')` - but it depends on the real meaning of  "Julian" dates.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add (count of days) -1  to 1st Jan of year

```
select to_date('20'||15||'01.01','yyyy.mm.dd') + 222-1 from dual

10/08/2015
```